# Cocos2d call random static sprite

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, sprite

I am trying to call a random static sprite from my plist. In this case it is a collectable orb, I have 4 images that I would like to randomly pick from named orb_0.png through to orb_3.png

I can call a single file image using and all is dandy.

```
 - (CCSprite *)sprite {
 if(_sprite == nil) {
 _sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"orb_0.png"];
```

However when I use the following code instead which is asking for the image but doesnt display them;

```
int randomOrb = rand( ) % 4;
 
 _sprite = [ CCSprite spriteWithFile:[ NSString stringWithFormat:@"orb_%d.png", randomOrb]];
```

What I get in the debugger says the images cannot be found repeatedly.

> 2014-04-25 18:58:16.322 MadScientist[2210:60b] cocos2d: CCFileUtils:
> Warning file not found: orb_0-hd.png
>
> 2014-04-25 18:58:16.323 MadScientist[2210:60b] cocos2d: CCTexture2D.
> Can't create Texture. UIImage is nil
>
> 2014-04-25 18:58:16.323 MadScientist[2210:60b] cocos2d: Couldn't add
> image:orb_0.png in CCTextureCache
>
> 2014-04-25 18:58:16.323 MadScientist[2210:60b] cocos2d: CCFileUtils:
> Warning file not found: orb_3-hd.png
>
> 2014-04-25 18:58:16.323 MadScientist[2210:60b] cocos2d: CCTexture2D.
> Can't create Texture. UIImage is nil
>
> 2014-04-25 18:58:16.324 MadScientist[2210:60b] cocos2d: Couldn't add
> image:orb_3.png in CCTextureCache

Comment: In your first expample you are using spriteWithSpriteFrameName but in your second you are using spriteWithFile. could that be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"orb*%d.png", randomOrb]];
That shoudl solve your problem.

Comment: _sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"orb_%d.png", randomOrb]];

I slightly adapted this to get it to work, Thanks Akaino

Comment: Oh ok, didn't recocgnize you were used to the spriteFrame. Must have overseen that. But I'm glad you made it run now!